# Отсутствие/наличие запятой

Tags: пунктуация, спп

Пожалуйста, помогите! Предложение: «Для Штольца главное - труд, но не как способ достичь покоя, любое стремление к которому Штольц называл "Обломовщиной"». Учитель указал как ошибку отсутствие запятой после слова "стремление", но я интуитивно чувствую (уверена!), что ее тут быть не должно. Она говорит, что это СПП и запятая нужна, но я не согласна. Пожалуйста, дайте ***аргументированное*** объяснение, почему не нужна запятая.

Comment: Какие аргументы могут быть против неграмотного учителя?! Правда, он мог устать и на автомате влепить запятую, завидев слово *который*. Наталья Вам всё по полочкам разложила.

Comment: Допустим, ошиблась. Но если она еще и настаивает, что так правильно, то как она может работать учителем?

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна, потому что *«любое стремление»* входит в придаточное, просто союзное слово расположено не сразу после запятой:

**Покой, любое стремление к которому – «обломовщина».**

Иначе – бессмыслица получается.

Comment: _Наталья: ...просто **подчинительный союз** расположен не сразу после запятой._ === А где Вы **союз** увидели?

Comment: Да, не союз, союзное слово. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Хотел бы добавить к ответу Натальи, что, если бы там нужна была запятая, тогда бы *"который"* относилось бы к слову *"стремление"*, а оно со всей очевидностью относится к *"покою"*.

Answer (score 0):

В примере, который Вы приводите, союзное слово "который" является членом предложения и стоит после определяемых им слов. Соответственно, запятая стоит не перед местоимением "который", а  перед словосочетанием, от которого зависит союзное слово.

В этом предложении запятая стоит между главной частью и зависимым предложением:

**…спо­соб дости­чь покоя (како­го?), любое стрем­ле­ние к кото­ро­му…**